# 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'itos'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am building ML models for NLP with pytorch, but as I define vocabulary for tekenized words in my text with "vacab" and try to use `vocab.itos` I get: 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'itos' error.

This is my vocab:

```
vocab = torchtext.vocab.vocab(counter, min_freq=1)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should access [`torchtext.vocab.Vocab.get_itos`](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html#torchtext.vocab.Vocab.get_itos) to get the indices->tokens mapping.

```
>>> itos = vocab.get_itos()
```

Comment: Ok, understood, do you also know alternative for vocab.stoi[s], I know that there is vocab.get_stoi() but that method doesn't accepts parameters and returns Dict. I just want index for that word (s) in my vocab?

Comment: Similarly you would use [`torchtext.vocab.Vocab.get_stoi`](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html#torchtext.vocab.Vocab.get_stoi).

Comment: Yes, but get_stoi doesn't accepts any parameters, but I need method that I can pass string (word) to...

Comment: Well why not just do: `stoi = vocab.get_stoi()`, then `stoi[s]`?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes or methods change, depending on the dataset (actually the class) you are using. I also tried to get 'itos' from my d2l.torch.Vocab object, but it did not work. I check the attributes and methods of the instance with dir.

data = d2l.MTFraEng(batch_size=128)
source_data = data.src_vocab
print(dir(source_data)

Among the responses, there is an attribute implemented called idx_to_token. So I only acceded to it.

print(source_data.idx_to_token)

And get the data :)

['!',',','.','','','','?','a','agree', ...,'works','write','you']