# Updating old code with new torch vocab methods (stoi and itos methods changed)

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, torchtext

I am trying to create a Japanese-English translation model following this Medium article.
https://arusl.medium.com/japanese-english-language-translation-with-transformer-using-pytorch-243738146806
Everything runs perfectly until the second to last cell, when I get an error running the translate function. The error is specifically on this line.

```
tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab.stoi[tok] for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)]+ [EOS_IDX]
```

The error: AttributeError: 'Vocab' object has no attribute 'stoi'. Since the article was written, the method .stoi has changed to get_stoi() → Dict[str, int] according to the torchtext documentation (https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html). When I attempt to change the line to the following, however, I get the error "Counter object has no attribute 'get_stoi'."

```
tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab.get_stoi()[tok] for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)]+ [EOS_IDX]
```

The same goes for the itos and get_itos() method. If I try to use the method as
Any help for how to make this work would be greatly appreciated as I'm very dumbfounded at the moment.

A similar question was asked here but I don't see how to implement the answer or make it work in this case. ['Vocab' object has no attribute 'itos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743912/vocab-object-has-no-attribute-itos)

Edit: This function seems suspect as it is creating vocab out of a counter... is there a better way to do this?

```
def build_vocab(sentences, tokenizer):
  counter = Counter()
  for sentence in sentences:
    counter.update(tokenizer.encode(sentence, out_type=str))
  return Vocab(counter)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... After reading the Medium article, I think you're encountering this error due to changes in the torchtext library's methods for vocabulary handling. The 'Vocab' object no longer has the 'stoi' attribute; it has been replaced with 'get_stoi()'. Similarly, 'itos' is now 'get_itos()'.

To fix the error, update your code:

Original code:

```
tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab.stoi[tok] for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)] + [EOS_IDX]
```

Updated code:

```
tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab.get_stoi()[tok] for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)] + [EOS_IDX]
```

Make the same change for 'itos' to 'get_itos()', if applicable.

Comment: This returns the error "AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'get_stoi'"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the code. How about you try ```tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab.get_stoi().get(tok, src_vocab.get_stoi()["<unk>"]) for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)] + [EOS_IDX]
```

Answer (score 0):

update code:
tokens = [BOS_IDX] + [src_vocab[tok] for tok in src_tokenizer.encode(src, out_type=str)] + [EOS_IDX]

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.